# Check if file is selected in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a button with file input. If I click on the button, I can choose a file from my computer. My problem is that I want to add alert if I select a file. How can I do this? I tried to solve this, but the alert appears when I click again on the button.

```js
function openfileDialog() {
    $("#fileLoader").click();
    if($("#fileLoader").val() !== ""){
        alert("You selected a file!");
    }
}
```

```css
#fileLoader
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" />
<input type="button" id="btnOpenFileDialog" value = "Click Me !!!" onclick="openfileDialog();" />
```

Comment: if you hide the fileLoader how can you upload a file,?

Comment: @KrishnaJonnalagadda The file selection dialog will appear when the element is sent a `click` event -- regardless of whether the element is visible or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" onchange="alert('selected');" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code. Basically, you need to use onchange event. (Fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/o2gxgz9r/65577/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var openfileDialog = function() {
    $("#fileLoader").click();    
  }

  $('#btnOpenFileDialog').click(openfileDialog);

  $("#fileLoader").change(function() {
    if ($("#fileLoader").val() !== "") {
      alert("You selected a file!");
    }
  })
});
```

Note - alert will appear only when file is selected initially and later if a new file is selected. If you want it to appear even if same file is selected, then you need to modify the value property of the `#fileLoader` in `openfileDialog` function

Answer (score 0):

Use `change` event for this but one about this is It will fire only when you pick different file if you pick same `file` that you already selected It won't fire again.

```js
function openfileDialog() {
    $("#fileLoader").click();
}

$("#fileLoader").on("change", function(e){
   if($("#fileLoader").val() !== ""){
        alert("You selected a file!");
    }
});
```

```css
#fileLoader
{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="fileLoader" name="files" title="Load File" />
<input type="button" id="btnOpenFileDialog" value = "Click Me !!!" onclick="openfileDialog();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi this might helpfull,

```
function openfileDialog() {
    $("#fileLoader").click();
      $('#fileLoader').change(function(){
              if($(this).val() != ""){
                alert("You selected a file!");
              }        
          })     
}
```